# By group, plot highest quantile data vs lowest, and capture stats

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I wish to group a dataset by "assay", then compare intensities for small cells versus large cells. The problem I have is that in writing my code I only understand how to group the top and bottom cellArea quantiles of the entire dataFrame, rather than for each individual assay ('wt' and 'cnt').

As a final point, I would like to compare the mean values between the intensities of the two groups for each assay type...

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = DataFrame({'assay':['cnt']*10+['wt']*10,
                'image':['001']*10+['002']*5+['001']*5,
                'roi':['1']*5+['2']*5+['3']*5+['1']*5,
                'cellArea':[99,90,50,2,30,65,95,30,56,5,33,18,98,76,56,72,12,5,47,89],
                'intensity':[88,34,1,50,2,67,88,77,73,3,2,67,37,34,12,45,23,82,12,1]},
               columns=['assay','image','roi','cellArea','intensity'])

df.loc[(df['cellArea'] < df['cellArea'].quantile(.20)),'group'] = 'Small_CellArea'
df.loc[(df['cellArea'] > df['cellArea'].quantile(.80)),'group'] = 'Large_CellArea'
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

sns.violinplot(data=df,y='intensity',x='assay',hue='group',capsize=1,ci=95,palette="Set3",inner='quartile',split=True, cut=0)
plt.ylim(-20,105)
plt.legend(loc='center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.08), ncol=3, frameon=True, fancybox=True, shadow=True, fontsize=12)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the low and high quantile by groups and then merge them back to the original data frame from where you can then calculate the `group` variable as `Small` or `large`:

```
from pandas import pd
quantileLow = df.groupby('assay').cellArea.quantile(0.2).reset_index()
quantileHigh = df.groupby('assay').cellArea.quantile(0.8).reset_index()
df = pd.merge(df, pd.merge(quantileLow, quantileHigh, on = "assay"), on = "assay")

df.loc[df['cellArea'] < df.cellArea_x,'group'] = 'Small_CellArea'
df.loc[df['cellArea'] > df.cellArea_y,'group'] = 'Large_CellArea'
```